# When is VS Code's setting css.lint.hexColorLength fired?

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

I'm creating a video series on all the VS Code settings, but I can't figure out where this `css.lint.hexColorLength` setting is relevant. When I input an incorrect hexadecimal value another error (`css-propertyvalueexpected`) fires. When is this setting relevant?

Screenshot:
[image: Expected a hex value error instead of the css-propertyvalueexpected error]

[Video explaning it.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5W93Pwv7BI&list=PLVwLx67OHLu1HIbCihg3cohaM5eCarbiQ&index=18)